# OpenCV: Smoothing color images and black and white text images for OCR

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I have implemented OCR to recognize numbers in documents and later I will hide the number like National Security Number/Resident registration number. The folder contains different types of color and black white images (passport, business documents).

The problem is that sometimes OCR could not detect the number and skip the number like in image **"Resident Registration Number"**. OCR skip the **"Resident Registration Number"** while it is clear.

**How to solve this problem?**

**Code**

```
import glob
import re
import string
from itertools import chain

# import self as self

from paddleocr import PaddleOCR, draw_ocr, PPStructure
import cv2
import os
import regex

pattern_8 = r'-\d{8}'
pattern_4 = r'-\d{4}'
my_path = "/media/cvpr/CM_1/COREMAX/testing/"


ocr = PaddleOCR(rec=True, use_angle=True, lang='korean', use_gpu=True)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/media/cvpr/CM_1/pytesseract/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

save_path = '/media/cvpr/CM_1/COREMAX/paddle/'

# Regex
passport_pattern = '^[A-Z0-9<]{9}[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{7}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}[A-Z0-9<]{14}[0-9]{2}$'

for img in glob.glob(my_path + '*.*'):
    img_bgr_rgb = cv2.imread(img)
    file_Name = os.path.basename(img)
    #image = img_bgr_rgb[:, :, ::-1]

    # Not Good results
    #thresh, im_bw = cv2.threshold(image, 210, 230, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    #cv2.imwrite("bw_image.jpg", im_bw)

    face_data = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img_bgr_rgb, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in face_data:
        roi = img_bgr_rgb[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi, (25, 25), cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED)
        img_bgr_rgb[y:y + roi.shape[0], x:x + roi.shape[1]] = roi

    result = ocr.ocr(img_bgr_rgb, cls=True)

    for x in result:
        if regex.search(r'\.[0-9.]+', str(x[1][0])):
            #print(x[1][0])
            x1 = int(x[0][0][0])
            y1 = int(x[0][0][1])
            x2 = int(x[0][2][0])
            y2 = int(x[0][2][1])
            cv2.rectangle(img_bgr_rgb, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 224), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(save_path, file_Name), img_bgr_rgb)
        elif '-' in str(x[1][0]):
            print(x[1][0])
            x1 = int(x[0][0][0])
            y1 = int(x[0][0][1])
            x2 = int(x[0][2][0])
            y2 = int(x[0][2][1])
            cv2.rectangle(img_bgr_rgb, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 224), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(save_path, file_Name), img_bgr_rgb)
```

**Output of OCR**

```
5318-864-2206-293
21i-87-50168
서울득벌시 강납구 논현로 149 길 67-7
57-7 Noihyeou-r0149-Bi
Gangnam-gu Seoull Korea
니1sd O -ilg s- [iSlticl 7a8 0016
```

**Output Image**

[image]

**Original Image**

[image]

Comment: Whats the difference between inpuıt and output image ? I couldnt notice. Also why the passport number disappears in the output image

Comment: Actually, I want to hide the data which contain "-" mostly security number contains "-" but OCR missed the resident registration number and little bit more wrong results. Thus, I want to add image processing techniques which can the accuracy of OCR.

Comment: did you also try other ocr methods ? like tesseract ? paddle ocr is able to read both alphabet english and korean ? Gaussian blur can be harmfull also

Comment: Yes, I have tried PaddleOCR blur is just for face.